# Remove header specific page

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I have the following page setup in App.js

```
StackNavigator({
   MyTab: {
     screen: TabNavigator({ }),
     navigationOptions: { title: 'Header title' }
  }
})
```

Bottom tab navigator with 4 screens in it: Home, Search, Card and Account. This tab navigator is inside stack navigator since i will be needing stack navigator to open other screens inside these pages.

In my case I don't need header in the Home page inside tab navigator. But according to this code every page inside tab navigator will have header. How can I achieve this?

Complete code flow is this.

**App.js**

```
import HomeScreen from './src/pages/HomeScreen';
import SearchScreen from './src/pages/SearchScreen';
import CartScreen from './src/pages/CartScreen';
import AccountScreen from './src/pages/AccountScreen';

const BottomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
    },
    Search: {
      screen: SearchScreen,
    },
    Cart: {
      screen: CartScreen,
    },
    Account: {
      screen: AccountScreen,
    },
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({focused, tintColor}) => {
        const {routeName} = navigation.state;
        return (
          <Image
            style={styles.iconSize}
            source={require('./src/assets/img/icon.png')}
          />
        );
      },
    }),
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    tabBarOptions: {
      style: {
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
      },
      showLabel: false,
      indicatorStyle: {
        backgroundColor: 'red',
      },
    },
    animationEnabled: true,
    swipeEnabled: false,
  },
);

const HomeStackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    HomeStack: {
      screen: BottomTabNavigator,
    },
  },
  {
    headerBackTitleVisible: false,
  },
);

export default createAppContainer(HomeStackNavigator);
```

**HomeScreen.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';

export default class HomeScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null,
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text> HomeScreen </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### UPDATE:

Try to update your parent stack

```
const HomeStackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    HomeStack: {
      screen: BottomTabNavigator,
    },
  },
  {
    headerBackTitleVisible: false,
    headerMode: 'none',
  },
);
```

### Old answer

Try below

```
export default class Home extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = () => {
        const navigationOptions = {
            header: null,
            headerMode: 'none',
        };
        return navigationOptions;
    };
}
```

Comment: this is not working. i have added the complete code in app.js. please have a look.

Comment: I just update my answer. Try to see if it works for you

Comment: this removed header for all pages. i need to remove header for only homescreen. i need header for other pages

Answer (score 1):

Just add `static navigationOptions` in your code just anywhere in the code except inside any method like render or componentDidMount, it will work

```
export default class Home extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        header: null
    }
}
```

Comment: glad it helped, do select as selected if you think this answer is correct.

Comment: this is not working. i have added the complete code in app.js. please have a look.

Comment: have you added   static navigationOptions = {
        header: null
    } in home.js?  share that code too

Comment: still you are getting the header?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204247/discussion-between-gaurav-roy-and-sallu-salman).